# Clear gps logger with sirf or nmea

Tags: java, gps, rxtx, nmea

I have an usb Canmore GPS Logger/Tracker I am developing an app to connect, I know there are plenty of apps that get the data, but I need some specs besides getting the information.

Anyways I can read the data from my gps logger, I have no problem obtaining the data. But I have problems deleting or clearing the data.
I was reading this
http://usglobalsat.com/downloads/NMEA_commands.pdf on page 21

[image: Reset Config]

I read the whole manual but I dont understand how  to send a clear history.  Like how am I supposed to send the valid hex  command with 2 or one at the end.

Comment: Do you know how to set a bit in a number? If not learn the basics of bit arithmetic. In your case, for reset you have to set Bit 3 to perform a factory reset. e.g set bit 1,2 and 3 = 2 + 4 + 8 = 14. So send the number 14 via SirFDemo

Comment: I dont have a problem with the bit arithmetic. I didnt know how to send the command  how to set the whole line, but I know understand it $PSRF101,0,0,0,000,0,0,12,4*10

Comment: The only difficult thing is to correctly calculate the checksum of the NMEA line.

Comment: ...which isn't difficult at all! You just xor every char with the result from the previous xor, starting after the $. Can be done in a one-liner.